# Two way SSL CA Security

Tags: security, ssl

Two way SSL using client certificate authentication.

Server S1 trusts a client certificate issued by CA1. Client C1 get a certificate CR1 signed by CA1. Now both S1 and C1 can communicate as C1 can present the CR1 signed by CA1.

Now the malicious client C2 get his certificate CR2 signed by CA1, CA1 will sign the certificate for malicious client C2. C2 can also communicate with the server as C2 has the CR2 which is signed by CA1.

My Question is: How is two way SSL secure then as any client can authenticate himself.

I think Server will validate the domain name or common name along with the client certificate. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your definition of "secure" and what your requirements are. You are correct that anyone with a certificate from a trusted certificate authority can connect to the server, so the security depends on how much you trust the certificate authorities which your server is configured with. That may include every public CA in the world, or you could limit it to an internal CA which you create yourself and only use to issue certificates to valid users of your system.

If a certificate is issued by a public CA, you could think of it as being a bit like using OpenID (e.g. logging in with Google) - the user's identity has been verified by someone else, but that doesn't mean you trust them. In practice, this isn't a common scenario. I haven't heard of a major site providing access based on certificates issued by a public CA. It might be something that you would use to secure communications between a client application and a server for example, where you create the certificates yourself.

Checking that the certificate was issued by a valid CA is as far as web servers usually go. 
You can make additional checks at the application level where you check the CN against a database of known users who are allowed to access the system, but I'm not aware of any servers which will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Client **authentication** only guarantees that certificate owner is indeed C1 or C2. It attaches some name to client which server can trust to be true.

Wherever server wants to communicate with this client, is a matter of **authorization** and completely out of scope of PKI/TLS/crypto. Server may give some information to C1 and immediately close connection with C2, or ask C2 to register with server, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Normally the CA should be restricted to only sign certificate requests from specific clients. So in that case CR2 is never signed, and this attack cannot even occur. If the signing itself cannot be avoided, then the identity of the client certificate can be used to thwart this attack. This is commonly the case if the Public Key Infrastructure (certificate tree & management) has been set up within the company instead of relying on a Trusted Third Party (commercial CA).

There are multiple options for avoiding this attack.

- If you have just a client or two (often the case for inter-machine communications (servers talking to each other), then instead of trusting the CA, you can directly trust the client certificates.
- You could also use an OCSP server for allowing only certain certificates.
- A white list using the serial number (and/or the hash - ID - of the certificates) could also be deployed. This check can be performed at application level; application servers can be configured to make the certificate available to servlets, for instance.

So all in all, it depends.

Comment: We sometimes do three of these measures. We like to err on the safe side :)